# Enqueing two different types of jQuery script in Wordpress from CDN

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cdn

I'm trying to enqueue two different versions of jQuery in my functions.php page of wordpress, the first one is the original one (I followed a tutorial on building a theme from scratch).

The second one should enable a range slider to work with ajax (it is working in the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wcepbL45/1/ , but is not firing when embedded into my wordpress site.)

Here is what I have in my functions.php

```
function include_jquery()
{
wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.1.3.min.js', '', 1, true);

    // !

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 
'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));

    // !

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');
```

Where am I going wrong? Does it make sense to be loading two different jQuery libraries, or does version 3 include version 2? Why is the range slider not firing in my wordpress?

Thanks !

Comment: you cannot use two different version of jQuery...................

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a javascript library, as per there description "jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers."... In short they've created a bunch of functions with **specific names** and place them in a file to make it easier.

You're loading 2 version (1 is recent the other one has at least 5 to 7 years) of the same file. **You're creating conflicts like never before** and **you're opening yourself to potential malicious actions and security vulnerabilities** by using such an old version.

**EDIT 1:**

Coming back to your problem then and following your last comment, you're not properly enqueuing scripts:

```
function include_jquery()
{
wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.1.3.min.js', '', 1, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 
'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery'); 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');
```

Both your scripts have the same handle, you have 2 add action with 1 inside a function, and one has a dependency to itself so you're pretty much in a never ending loop.

```
/**
* Theme scripts
*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {

    /**
    * Register then enqueue jquery js
    *
    * Check if CDN's url is valid, if not return fallback
    */
    $test_jquery_js = @fopen( 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', 'r' );
    if ( $test_jquery_js !== false ) {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' );
    } else {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array() );
    };
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js' );

  };
};
```

This is the proper way to enqueue scripts. you can learn more about `wp_enqueue_script` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Okay sure. Can you think of any reason the range slider (in the jsfiddle) is not firing when embedded in my wordpress site? I put the slider both in the footer and the front-page, and code in the scripts.js . Neither of them are firing the slideStop command that works in the jsfiddle

Comment: hey, thanks ! I just changed the code. But my range slider is still not functioning, nothing is happening on slideStop (like it should in the jsfiddle ? I don't understand why it isn't registering?